# How do I increase the height of a div to make sure the whole background-image is shown?

Tags: css, image

I want to have div that have an image as background and content in the foreground.
The background image should always completely be shown.
To make sure of that scale the image so that the width of image and the div is the same and then increase the height of the div so that the whole background image is shown.
If the div is already high enough then show a white background at the lower half.

I found answers, that only work if the div has no content (for example [How to auto fit the height of a div to its background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47876954/how-to-auto-fit-the-height-of-a-div-to-its-background-image)) but not for divs that have a content.

I tried to set

```
.example{
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/12/200/100); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
<div class="example" style="width:300px;">
    This should be 150px heigh;
</div>
```

But that stretched the image and didn't increase the height of the div.

Alternative I tried to not use a background-image and put a img and the content into the div and use posion:absolute

```
.example2{
    position:relative;
}

.example2img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

.example2inner{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}

<div class="example2" style="width:150px;">
    <img class="example2img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/12/200/100">
    <div class="example2inner">
        This should as high as it needs to be to fit the content. {a lot of content}
    </div>
</div>
```

But that has the problem that the div doesn't scale with the height of the content and if there is a lot of content then the div will not increase in size.

You can find these example under
https://jsfiddle.net/qk0aLemy/1/

Comment: You know the image will be cut off either height or width if it cover the whole div right? Then why not use `background-size: cover`?

Comment: I want it not cut off. If it would cut off the top/bottom, it should resize the div and if it would cut off left/right it should shrink the image and let the bottom part empty.